# Eigenvalues of real symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

There are related posts but i want to ask for not the proof but motivation for the proof why real symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues.

One way is to use ,assuming $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$:

$$\lambda \langle v, v \rangle = \langle Av, v \rangle = \langle v, A^*v \rangle = \langle v, Av \rangle = \bar\lambda\ \langle v, v \rangle.$$

So, as eigenvector is nonzero, eigenvalue is real. But it seems like it is just so because one has defined the inner product in such a way that multiplication on the right side by x amount changes the product by $\bar{x}$ times, but what if we did not define it this way , then one could not get anything? My point is , this seems like , not saying it is , like an arbitrary choice in the definition causes some non trivial consequences. Also for example, now the characteristic polynomial in degree $n$ will have real roots , where it is not always easy to see that all roots of a polynomial is real, consider a 3rd, 4th, ... degree polynomial, but from this it must be.

So, what is actually going on? I kinda want to see the background of what's happening here,as I dont think this proof is very insightful, or any tips to explore would be nice.

Comment: One way to think about what’s going on is that a real symmetric matrix “really” describes a quadratic function. Completing the square allows you to “diagonalize” this quadratic function (write it as a sum of squares). There’s more to be done before you know that you can diagonalize it as a quadratic form and also as a linear map simultaneously, but that’s a key part (for me) of understanding the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: But i did not get which quadratic are you talking about? I have some knowledge about Spectral theorem that (only as i think)  self adjoint linear maps have diagonal form with real eigenvalues ,but not getting how this really describes quadratic function.

Comment: For instance the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2&3\\3&1\end{bmatrix}$$ describe the quadratic function $$ [x y] A \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = 2x^2 + 6xy + y^2. $$

Comment: Okay , i think i understood . The thing is say (x,y,..)  is an eigenvector , then eigenvalue squared is nonnegative so it is real ,if this is what you meant

Comment: Consider the function $x\mapsto\langle Ax,x\rangle$ on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$. This is a continuous function defined on a compact set. It attains a global maximum at some unit vector $u$. Consequently, for every real unit vector $v\perp u$, the function $f(t)=\langle A(u\cos t+v\sin t),\,u\cos t+v\sin t\rangle$ attains global maximum at $t=0$. Therefore $f'(0)=0$, i.e. $\langle Au,v\rangle=0$ for every $v\perp u$. Hence $Au\in\left((\operatorname{span}\{u\})^\perp\right)^\perp=\operatorname{span}\{u\}$, meaning that $Au=\lambda u$ for some real number $\lambda$...

Comment: Now, if $Q$ is any real orthogonal matrix whose first column is $u$, then $Q^TAQ=\pmatrix{\lambda&0\\ 0&A_{n-1}}$ for some symmetric matrix $A_{n-1}$. So, inductively, we see that $A$ has a real spectrum.

Comment: What I meant is not that all squared eigenvalues of matrices are real (that isn't true). I meant that the real reason symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues is the proof @user1551 gives above, which shows that the process of completing the square can be done in a way that also serves to find a basis that is a basis of eigenvectors. That basis is one in which the matrix is diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

For matrices, you don't need to define the inner product to be *anything at all* to prove that the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real.  However, defining $\ \langle v, w\rangle\ $ to be $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^n v_i\overline{w_i}$ for vectors with $\ n\ $ complex entries, and showing that it has all the properties required of an inner product, does provide you with a tool that allows you make the proof more succinct and elegant.

If you take the inner product in your proof to be the one I've defined above, for example, and write it out in full, it becomes the following
\begin{align}
\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n|v_i|^2&=
\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{v_i}v_i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\overline{v_i}a_{ij}v_j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nv_ja_{ji}\overline{v_i}\\
&=\overline{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\overline{v_j}a_{ji}v_i}\\
&=\overline{\lambda\sum_{j=1}^n\overline{v_j}v_J}\\
&=\overline{\lambda}\sum_{j=1}^n|v_j|^2\ .
\end{align}
which gives you $\ \lambda=\overline{\lambda}\ $ because an eigenvector, by definition, must be non-zero.  There's nothing in this form of the proof that relies on our having defined the inner product in a particular way.  The reliance is, in fact, the other way round. Defining the inner product as I've done above allows you to eliminate all the summation signs from the above proof, and turn it into the simple, elegant proof you give in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "choose the inner product". Rather, the very notion of being symmetric is directly related to the choice of inner product. If you change the inner product, then you also change what it means to be symmetric.

If you want, here is a different version of the theorem: let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$, and let $\sigma$ be an involutive anti-automorphism of the ring $End_K(V)$ (so $\sigma^2=Id$, and $\sigma(uv)=\sigma(v)\sigma(u)$: $\sigma$ reverses the product). We have $K\subset End_K(V)$ if we see scalars as homotheties, and $\sigma$ restricts to some field automorphism of $K$. Then for any $u\in End_K(V)$ such that $\sigma(u)=u$, its eigenvalues in $K$ are invariant under $\sigma$.

If $K=\mathbb{C}$ and the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex conjugation, then $\sigma$ corresponds to the adjoint for a certain inner product on $V$, and $\sigma(u)=u$ exactly means that $u$ is symmetric (self-adjoint) for this inner product, and the conclusion of the theorem says that its eigenvalues are real.

This version shows that the proof with the inner product is not just a trick, it is used because the very notion of symmetry is actually with respect to some inner product. It's just that, as often with matrices, this is hidden because matrices are linear maps after some choice of basis, and a choice of basis implies many things; for instance, any choice of basis leads to a "natural inner product" relative to this basis, and the conjugate-transposition of matrices is the involution $\sigma$ that corresponds to this inner product.